# Views help from Advanced Help isn't being displayed or I can't find it

Tags: views

**It turns out that I actually hadn't installed Advanced Help on this Drupal setup and was only using regular 'Help'**

I'm using Views 7.x-3.5 (API version 3) and Drupal 7.17

I installed Advanced Help (some time ago now) and cleared all caches

When I go to /admin/help I see a list of the following...

```
Help topics

Help is available on the following items:

Administration menu
Advanced User Management
Block
CKEditor
Color
Comment
Content Access
Contextual links
Dashboard
Database logging

Date
Field
Field SQL storage
Field UI
File
Filter
Help
Image
List
Menu

Menu Block
Node
Number
Options
Path
Pathauto
RDF
Rules
Rules Forms Support
Search

System
Taxonomy
Text
ThemeKey
Token
Trigger
User
Webform
```

The following is constantly displayed in structure > views

> If you install the advanced help module from http://drupal.org/project/advanced_help, Views will provide more and better help. Hide this message.

Comment: The module you need to install is called _Advanced Help_, not _Advanced Views_

Comment: Sorry, yes I'm getting myself confused here, must not have been using Advanced Help at all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install the [advanced help module](https://drupal.org/project/advanced_help)

> When this module is installed, users with the view advanced help index
>   permission can access the advanced help index by going to Administer
>   -> Advanced Help (http://www.example.com/admin/advanced_help). Additional view advanced help popup and view advanced help topic
>   permissions enable them to access the actual help pages and popups.

Comment: Thanks, yeh I think I'm getting myself confused here. Cheers - must not have been using Advanced Help at all!